# How to disable the Delete Option in Tagged Value Window of Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enterprise-architect

I am using enterprise architect through C# add-in and we have several elements with few tagged values. Now how can we disable the delete option of tagged values in a tagged value window through Add-in/EA-MDG. On what event this can be called? In worst case at least how to prompt with a pop-up saying that (((Are you sure you want to delete this tagged value[yes][no]))) when i select this delete option of tagged value in the tagged value window.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable the delete function, and there is also no event that gets fired when a tagged value is deleted.

The only tagged value specific events are documented here: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/tagged_value_broadcasts.html

So I guess the only thing you can do is to use the context item events to capture the tagged values when an element is selected and validate those same tagged values when a new element is selected. If the user deleted a tagged value that he wasn't supposed to, at least you still have your cached version of it and can recreate it.

Comment: Even security does not offer an according option.